# How to get currently displayed level of level-list

Tags: android, list, drawable

I've created level-list drawable and I'm changing its levels by setImageLevel(int), but I'd like to check which level is currently set. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What is a level-list drawable ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getLevel()

is inherited by LevelListDrawable.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I figured it out seconds before you wrote the answer, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I'd certainly like to, but I still have too low reputation so I am not allowed to do so. Sorry.